# Need to convert the Pandas DataFrame to list of lists?

Tags: python, list, pandas, dataframe

I have used the below code to get a list.

```
 df['Column'].values.tolist()
```

Pandas DataFrame return the data like this

```
['tropical fruit,yogurt,coffee', 'pip fruit','yogurt,cream cheese ,meat spreads', 'whole milk','butter,yogurt,rice,abrasive cleaner']
```

But i need to get the data like this

```
[['tropical fruit','yogurt','coffee'],['pip fruit'],['yogurt','cream cheese' ,'meat spreads'],['whole milk'],['butter','yogurt','rice','abrasive cleaner']]
```

Comment: some data please.

Comment: you want to split tropical and fruit but not cream cheese?

Comment: No.  data return from one column , the column have multiple strings split by  comma  ","

Comment: @WannaBeCoder sorry That was mistake. I Changed the questions . tropical and fruit are same string. no need to split.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[ s.split(',') for s in df['Column'].values.tolist()]
```

or possibly

```
df['Column'].str.split(',').values.tolist()
```

Comment: This answer returns what I want.